# Show Hide Elements(Form) Using Radio Buttons

Tags: jquery, radio-button, forms

I am trying to show and hide an element which is a `form` using a radio. I have made an attempt but still nothing works. Can anyone give me some guidance?

```
$('input[name="radio-3"]').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "radio-3") {
        $("details").show();
    } else {
        $("details").hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<div id = "radioButton">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-3">
    <label for="radio-3">I want you to create my artwork</label>
</div>
<div id="details">
    <form>
        Please leave your name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>

        Email:<br>
        <input type ="email" name ="email"><br>
</div>
<div id="detailsSecond">
    Please leave us a description of your artwork brief: <br>
    <textarea name = "textarea" rows="10" cols="50">Write something here</textarea>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('input[name="radio-1"]').click(`, I think you need `checkbox` rather than `radio` button, Also I would suggest you to use `change` event

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: Note that your HTML is invalid as you close the parent `div` before the `form`. You should change it so that the `form` wraps both divs

Comment: @cazlouise https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/eupb6m2r/2/ Also prefix `#` when using ID selector